Springboot issue while sending post request on Postman , unexpected http error
`My code :
config :
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);


//    @Autowired
//    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder; // Assuming you're using BCrypt

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
//                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll() // Allow /login endpoint without authentication
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                            LOGGER.info("Authentication successful, redirecting to login (check configuration?)"); // Log a message if redirecting after login
                            // You can replace the default behavior here if needed
                            response.sendRedirect("/home"); // Redirect to a different page (optional)
                        }))
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                        .permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }} 

controller :
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<RegistrationResponse> registerUser(@RequestBody UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto) {
        RegistrationResponse response = userService.addUser(userRegisterDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, response.isSuccess() ? HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody UserLoginDto userLoginDto) {
        String loginStatus = userService.login(userLoginDto);
        if (loginStatus.equals("Successful Login")) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(loginStatus, HttpStatus.OK); // 200 OK for successful login
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(loginStatus, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED); // 401 Unauthorized for failed login
        }
    }

}

register dto  :
package com.streak.dsastreak.entity;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class UserRegisterDto {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String name;
}


details  :
package com.streak.dsastreak.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint default 0")
    private long streak;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint default 0")
    private long numberOfQuestions;

    public UserDetails(String userName, String password, String name, int streak, int numberOfQuestions) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.streak = streak;
        this.numberOfQuestions = numberOfQuestions;
    }
}


service impl  :
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public RegistrationResponse addUser(UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto) {
        if (userRepo.existsByUserName(userRegisterDto.getUserName())) {
            return new RegistrationResponse(false, "User Already Exists. Please Login!"); // Registration failed
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails(userRegisterDto.getUserName(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(userRegisterDto.getPassword()),
                userRegisterDto.getName(), 0, 0); // Set streak and questions to 0

        userRepo.save(userDetails);
        return new RegistrationResponse(true, "User Registered Successfully!"); // Registration successful
    }

    @Override
    public String login(UserLoginDto userLoginDto) {
        UserDetails user = userRepo.findByUserName(userLoginDto.getUserName());
        if(user!=null && passwordEncoder.matches(userLoginDto.getPassword(),user.getPassword()))
        {
            return "Successful Login";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid Username or password";
        }
    }

properties :
spring.application.name=dsastreak

server.port=8082

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/streak
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
spring.security.crypto.password=bcrypt

pom :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.streak</groupId>
    <artifactId>dsastreak</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dsastreak</name>
    <description>DSA STREAK project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.11</version> <!-- Use the version of Spring Boot you are using -->
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



WHILE RUNNING THIS ON POSTMAN FOR REGISTER , POST REQUEST IT GIVES THIS ERROR ,
when i send request on postman : http://localhost:8082/register , i get this on my intellij console log :2024-05-09T21:03:08.845+05:30 WARN 3828 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] , what is happening ,HELP
everything has been mentioned above``your text`

Can you supply screen shot with your postman request. Do you really send POST?

your register method is post,but your request is get?
